# Is there a Sword Art Online manga?

Tags: sword-art-online

So I was wondering if there is a Sword Art Online manga, and if so which is the original, the manga or the anime?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Sword Art Online* started as a [light novel series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sword_Art_Online#Light_novels) (in 2009), and spawned [five manga adaptations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sword_Art_Online#Manga) (starting in 2010) and [an anime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sword_Art_Online#Anime) (in 2012). However, to my knowledge, the anime is based entirely on the first four volumes of the light novels and does not borrow from the manga material  at all.

Comment: Are the mangas based on the light novels?

Comment: @Cyberson Somewhat. The *Aincrad* and *Fairy Dance* manga are based on the main arcs from the light novels, and the *Progressive* manga is based on the *Progressive* light novel. The others are only based on the universe, not the story.

Answer (score 2):

At the time of writing (July 2014), there are currently [8 manga adaptations](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%BD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%82%A2%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88%E3%83%BB%E3%82%AA%E3%83%B3%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3#.E6.BC.AB.E7.94.BB) of the series, all written by [Kawahara Reki](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/people.php?id=107067), the original author of [Sword Art Online](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sword_Art_Online) light novel series.

- *Sword Art Online: Aincrad* 『ソードアート・オンライン アインクラッド』

  Illustrated by [中村]{Nakamura} [貯子]{Tamako}. Serialized from September 2010 to May 2012.

  Adapt the Aincrad arc (volume 1 and 2 of the light novel series).
- *Sword Art Online: Fairy Dance* 『ソードアート・オンライン フェアリィ・ダンス』

  Illustrated by [葉月]{Hazuki} [翼]{Tsubasa}. Serialized from May 2012 to May 2014.

  Adapt Fairy Dance arc (volume 3 and 4 of the light novel series).
- *Sword Art Online: Phantom Bullet* 『ソードアート・オンライン ファントム・バレット』

  Illustrated by [山田]{Yamada} [孝太郎]{Koutarou}. Serialize from May 2014.

  Adapt the Phantom Bullet arc (volume 5 and 6 of the light novel series).
- *Sword Art Online: Caliber* 『ソードアート・オンライン キャリバー』

  Illustrated by [木谷]{Kiya} [椎]{Shii}. Serialize from September 2014.

  Adapt the Caliber arc, a chapter from volume 8 *Sword Art Online: Early and Late* of the light novel series.
- *Sword Art Online: Mother's Rosario* 『ソードアート・オンライン マザーズ・ロザリオ』

  Illustrated by [葉月]{Hazuki} [翼]{Tsubasa}. Serialize from July 2014.

  Adapt the Mother's Rosario arc (volume 7 of the light novel series).
- *Sword Art Online: Girls Ops* 『ソードアート・オンライン ガールズ・オプス』

  Illustrated by [猫猫]{Nekobyou} [猫]{Neko}. Serialize from July 2013.

  An original story starring Leafa, Silica, Lizbeth with ALO as the stage.
- *Sword Art Online: Progressive* 『ソードアート・オンライン プログレッシブ』

  Illustrated by [比村]{Himura} [奇石]{Kiseki}. Serialize from August 2013.

  Adapt *Sword Art Online: Progressive* light novels, but from Asuna's point of view.
- *Sword Art☆Online* 『そーどあーと☆おんらいん。』

  Illustrated by 南十字星. Serialize from September 2010.

  A comedy 4-panel manga.